# The account summary for a site shows two numbers, why?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

The summary for the account shows two nubers as reputation, one under the image and one on the bar as a menu on "reputation earned". In all my accounts the later is significantly lower than the former. Do they mean different things? If so, what are the differences?

(not really a problem, just wondering)

Comment: Which two numbers, exactly, are you talking about? The number in the top bar *does* live refresh, though. So if it's been a bit since you refreshed the page, it's perfectly possible that it wouldn't match another number next to your name elsewhere on the page. There are also some numbers which are cached for a while before updating again.

Comment: @animuson If you click on the top bar's icon for the account, an account summary page shows up. At upper right the image and reputation, at center left a menu line including reputation (clicking that goes to show detailed changes). They are diferent, and by several hundred points in some cases (i.e., not just some caching issue).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the number you're talking about:

[image: Reputation Tab]

That number does not indicate your *current* reputation for your account. It represents the *change in reputation* that has occurred on your account since the last time you looked at that tab.

So, assuming you've looked at that tab in the past, if you go a long time without looking at it again, that number can grow rather large. Once you've looked at the tab again, though, the number will reset back to 0 and start over.

So in the image I've provided, I can conclude that I've earned 90 reputation since the last time I looked at that tab.

Comment: Yes, that is it. But I have looked at my Unix&Linux account recently, definitely not 3500-something reputation ago.